# Multiple Selection in Enquiry Page - Mailing Function

Tags: php, multipleselection, mailing

Actually Im working on a enquiry page where I have Multiple Selection Options and which I want it on the mail once user Select Multiple options and submit the form.  For this I have done below code, but failed to understand the problem, Please help me friends...

This is HTML Code

```
<select id="lstFruits" name="product_drop[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Orange Color ">Orange Color </option>
<option value="Red  Color">Red Color</option>
<option value="Black Color">Black Color</option>
<option value="Purple Color">Purple Color</option>
</select>
```

And a PHP code for mailing function I used below code, which is working and other fields like name, no, cname, mail & message are receiving on the mail but just this multiple selection thing is not coming to the mail. prod=implode is not working..

```
<?php
$name    =  trim($_POST['name']);
$no    =  trim($_POST['no']);
$cname  =  trim($_POST['cname']);
$mail     =  trim($_POST['mail']);
$mess   =  trim($_POST['message']);

if(isset($_POST['product_drop']))
{
$prod=implode(',',$_POST['product_drop']);
}


$redirect_to = 'https://www.google.com';
$a="";

$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Enquiry Received from Website";
$message = "Name: " . $name ."\r\nContact No.: " . $no ."\r\nCompany Name: "
. $cname . "\r\nMessage: " . $mess . "\r\nProduct: " . $prod."";    

$from = "Website";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .="Cc: ". $a . "\r\n";


$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF\n";


if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    header("Location: $redirect_to");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: Do a vardump  of products

Comment: Are you sure, you have `select` inside your form? Add full html of your form

Comment: yes I'm sure I have kept select inside my form...

Comment: fluidpowercontrol.com/enquiry/medical2.html - this is a enquiry page.

Answer (score 0):

You are Just one Step Back Keep Working Bro

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="lstFruits" name="product_drop[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Orange Color ">Orange Color </option>
<option value="Red  Color">Red Color</option>
<option value="Black Color">Black Color</option>
<option value="Purple Color">Purple Color</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_POST){
$array = array(); // Define it array
$array = $_POST['product_drop']; /// This will be Array
$values = implode(",", $array);
echo $values; // Work Done 
}
?>
```